# Get last modified date of a specific page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

The homepage of my Wordpress site needs to display the last modified date of another linked page. How can I get that dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the ID of the page that you want to get the date of.  Let's assume that you have that saved as a variable `$page_id`, then can get the post modified date in local or GMT time like this:

```
// Get the time/date in local time
$modified_date = get_post_field( 'post_modified', $page_id );

// Get the time/date in GMT time
$modified_date_gmt = get_post_field( 'post_modified_gmt', $page_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo get_the_modified( '', 18 );?> // 18 is the post ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php get_the_modified_date( $d, $post ); ?>
```

Parameters

```
$d
(string)
```

(optional) Optional PHP date format. Defaults to the "date_format" option.
Default:

```
$post
(int or WP_Post)
```

(optional) Optional Post ID or WP_Post object. Defaults to current post.
Default: 'null'